# How to update a single page content in a ViewPager without scrolling to the first page?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I want to update a specific page in a `ViewPager`, and stay on that page and not scroll to the first page

I tried to update the data list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it scrolls to the first page, `ViewPager` doesn't have `notifyItemChanged()` as `RecyclerView`.

Comment: User is on tab X you want from there to update tab Y?

Comment: No, I want to update tab y once I move to it

Answer (score 0):

Some code would help understand the problem better, showing what you are trying to update on the page and what you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on.

Your question and comment are two separate problems.

1. You are on Tab Y and you want to update Tab Y
2. You are on Tab X and you want to update Tab Y when you change to it.

Usually for problem 1, this can be handled within the code for that Tab(page)

For Problem 2 in general if you want to do something when you move to a page then you need to add a `OnPageChangeListener` but this might only be the start of what you need to do to update the Tab(page).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int)

```java
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (position == 1 || position == 2)
                {
                    // do something here
                }

                if (position == 0)
                {
                    // do something else
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // Code goes here
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Code goes here
            }
        });
```

But also without code I cannot tell if you have implemented the adapter in a way allows it to key the current page active when `notifyDataSetChanged()` as

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/PagerAdapter.html#top_of_page

> PagerAdapter supports data set changes. Data set changes must occur on the main thread and must end with a call to notifyDataSetChanged() similar to AdapterView adapters derived from BaseAdapter. A data set change may involve pages being added, removed, or changing position. The ViewPager will keep the current page active provided the adapter implements the method getItemPosition(Object).

Answer (score 0):

two ways to achieve this.

**Option (1)**
it's easier, but a bit inefficient.

Override getItemPosition in your PagerAdapter like this:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

This way, when you call notifyDataSetChanged(), the view pager will remove all views and reload them all.

**Option (2)**
is to setTag() for the views in instantiateItem(). Then instead of using notifyDataSetChanged(), you can use findViewWithTag() to find the view you want to update.